# Advantages of blob over video url

Tags: blob

I have trawled the internet looking at why blob videos are used but I am not tech savy enough to really understand it. Can someone explain simply why a blob URL for my video is better (if it is) than loading the src as /video/intro.mp4.

Here is the code that I have used. Which one is better for my use case?

`<video rel='preload' as='video' id='bgvid'>
   <source type='video/mp4' src='/video/intro.mp4' />
</video>`

or

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', videoURL, true);
req.responseType = 'blob';

req.onload = function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        var videoBlob = this.response;
        var vid = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob); // IE10+
        var video = document.getElementById('bgvid');
        video.autoplay = true;
        video.src = vid;
     }
  }
  req.onerror = function() {
     // Error
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say the regular html way because it does not take extra time to process because the html is built right into the webpage